# For a trampoline of arbitrary form, do all the attached (equal) springs stretch out to obtain the same $E_{pot}$ when placing a mass on it?

Tags: potential-energy, spring

Most trampolines have a circular shape. When a mass is placed on them (in equilibrium), so it won't roll to somewhere else on the trampoline)  all the equal springs stretch out by the same amount due to the circular and thus symmetrical form.

But what about trampolines which have arbitrary forms? Will the springs closest to the mass which is placed on it in a state of equilibrium stretch the most and the ones the farthest from the mass be stretched the less?

Comment: Even for a circular trampoline I think that there is asymmetry in spring stretching unless the mass is in the middle?

Comment: I think he meant placing a round mass on the trampoline and letting it roll to its stable point.

Answer (score 0):

**No.**

Consider a rectangle trampoline of mat dimensions 2m by 10m. A weight is placed in the center and the mat sags by .1m below equilibrium plane (making the usual assumptions of spherical vacuums or whatever). This forms an angle between the new mat position and the equilibrium position, with the springs and mat along the hypotenuse; this is why the springs must stretch.

Since the trampoline is longer one way than the other, the mat angle differs depending on which edge you look at (and where along the edge, but let's not complicate things here). At the center of the long side, the angle is arctan(.1) = 5.7 degrees, so the springs must stretch by .1/sin (5.7degree) = 6.8cm. On the other axis though, the angle is 1.1 degrees in a 5m edge-to-center length, so the springs must stretch by 209cm.

Answer (score 0):

No.  The fabric is not isotropic.  Jumping on a trampoline a large fraction of the energy is stored in the springs that are in line with the main axis of the weave.

On my trampoline, once you get 4 springs away from the springs closest in line with the weave, the displacement is about 1/10 that of the closest spring.  My tramp has 140 springs.  About 20 springs really do most of the work.